# Which way can I put into WinCC OA data from external DB?

Tags: wincc-oa

I need to receive data to my WinCC OA project from external MSSQL. Are there any internal functions in WinCC OA to request DB? If that can only be done with Qt, where can i find instructions to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version you are using there are various ways of retrieving data from a database. If you want to access data programatically, you can use the *ActiveX Data Objects* (ADO) functions that are provided by the control interpreter.

Information about available functions can be found in the *WinCC OA Documentation*. The easiest way is to search for a function called `dbOpenConnection` and handle yourself further from there.
As the code is executed in the control interpreter itself, it is independendt from Qt.

Comment: Vers. 3.18. Thx for the tip

Comment: @Delay: Glad I could help. If you need any further assistance, drop me a message ;-)